# Pass map to function in OpenLayers3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

The code snippet below creates a map variable locally inside an init() function.  I am getting errors such as *this.map.getLayers* and *map.getLayers is not a function* or *cannot read property getLayers of undefined*, depending on how I call the function updateFliter()

If I remove the var in front of map, js creates a global variable, and updateFilter() works.

How can I call  updateFliter() without creating map as a global variable?

FYI, updateFilter() is implementing a CQL filter on the geoserver layers.

```
function init() {
    var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.text = "layer1";
    option2.text = "layer2";
    document.getElementById("dropdown").add(option1);
    document.getElementById("dropdown").add(option2);



    var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
           new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.OSM(),
                name: 'OpenStreetMap'
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: '../../geoserver/foo/wms',
                    params: {'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        tiled: true,
                        LAYERS: 'foo:layer1',
                        tilesOrigin: -181.800003051758     + "," + -66.7399978637695
                   }
               }), name: 'layer1'
            }),
            new ol.layer.Tile({
                source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
                    url: '../../geoserver/foo/wms',
                    params: {'VERSION': '1.1.1',
                        tiled: true,
                        LAYERS: 'foo:layer2',
                        tilesOrigin: -181.800003051758     + "," + -66.5354995727539,
                   }
               }), name: 'layer2'
            })
          ]
        }) 

    var updateFunc =     document.getElementById('updateFilterButton');
    updateFunc.addEventListener('click',     function(){updateFilter(map)});
}




//Use a CQL filter to select data to display
function updateFilter(map){
    var filterParams = {'CQL_FILTER': null};
    var filter =     document.getElementById('CQLfilter').value;
         //by default, reset all filters
    if (filter.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/,     '') != "") {
        filterParams["CQL_FILTER"] = filter;
    }
        this.map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
          if (lyr.get('name') == dropdown.value){
          lyr.getSource().updateParams(filterParams);
          };
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `updateFilter` function change `this.map` to just `map`.

Here's a minimal example ([Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/knWhhY6GWovWCriO7n11?p=preview)):

```
function init() {
    var map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            name: 'OpenStreetMap'
        })
      ],
      view: new ol.View({ 
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
          zoom: 2 
      })
    }) 

    var updateFunc = document.getElementById('updateFilterButton');
    updateFunc.addEventListener('click', function(){updateFilter(map)});
}

function updateFilter(map){
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      console.log(lyr)
    });
}

init()
```

If you are wondering why there still is a global variable `map`, it is due to the `<div>` with that ID (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables) on Stackoverflow).

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I thought I had tried that already: something must have been different.